# Packet Tracer 6.x on kubuntu 15.10 : unfind libkdeinit5_PacketTracer6.so

Tags: networking, kubuntu, cisco

I've tried to install the 6.2 and 6.3 version of Packet Tracer but when I run it I get this error message from plasma:

[image: Screenshot]

```
Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_PacketTracer6.so
```

Nothing happens if I execute PT in a terminal. I tried to find some information on google but came up empty.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem, I have solved it:

First, don't execute Packet Tracer with the icon or with the command "packettracer" because it'll give you false information or nothing at all.

So to debug your packet tracer go to the installation directory (default: /opt/pt) and in the bin folder execute the command PacketTracer6 and you get the missing dependencies:

```
sillicius@DIY1:/opt/pt/bin$ ./PacketTracer6                                                           
./PacketTracer6: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Solution:

Install libsll1.0.0:i386 (64bits versions doesn't work with PT) and link it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcrypto.so.1.0.0:i386    
$ sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Next dependencies not found:

```
/opt/pt/bin$ ./PacketTracer6                                                                  
./PacketTracer6: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Solution:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libqtwebkit4:i386
```

.

```
/opt/pt/bin$ ./PacketTracer6     
./PacketTracer6: error while loading shared libraries: libQtScriptTools.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Solution:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-scripttools:i386
```

After this, PT worked correctly for me.